# How to get user information from hippo via HST

Tags: hippocms

I'm evaluating the hippo cms, 
after add hst-security as a dependence ,so public site need login, but how can I fetch the login user's detail information like email and something else.
I used HstRequest.getUserPrincipal ,but only get the username. 
and tried to write a query "SELECT_USER_QUERY = "SELECT *  FROM hipposys:user"
but only get a user 'liveuser', after login with admin.
so , Anyone can help me ,how can I　get the detail info?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
    final User user = JcrSessionUtils.getHippoSession(request.getRequestContext().getSession()).getUser();
    user.getEmail();
    user.getLastLogin()
```